# can't add products (prestashop 1.7)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I can't add products in PrestaShop 1.7, when I want to add pictures doesn't allow me, also its show me the old categories that I had already deleted, also when I put the price doesn't give me the TTC price automatically, its something like the javascript is disabled, how I can solve this problem?

Comment: is it your latest version of 1.7?

Comment: yes the latest 1.7.2.4

Answer (score 0):

try clear cache ( Advanced Parameters -> Performance )